# Align div vertically in the middle

Tags: css

I'm trying to align some DIVs and failing to succeed.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="name"><h3>Some long name in here</h3></div>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="delete">X</div>
        <div class="price">1000.00</div>    
      </div>
</div>
```

This is what I did so far https://jsfiddle.net/uvo2xdxk/

How can I make the .info div to be vertically aligned inside the row?

Comment: Wow, the good old vertically center problem with CSS. Haven't they made it easy yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by `display: table-cell;`
Remove `float` from `.name` and `.info` and assign `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to them :)

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.name {
  background-color: red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.delete {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.price {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.info {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: ccc;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="name">
    <h3>Some long name in here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="delete">X</div>
    <div class="price">1000.00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Info box shall be right aligned as well, price and X shall stick to the right side.

Comment: @Eugen Check now, I've updated the answer

Comment: yep, that's now perfect! thx

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/uvo2xdxk/5/

try this one

```
.row {
    width: 450px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:table;
}
.row {
    width: 450px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:table;
}
```

assign row display:table; property and its child display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle; and also remove the float:right; from child

Comment: No, price shall have 5px from the right side. Both Price and X must be right side aligned.

Comment: just put     text-align: right; you can check it now https://jsfiddle.net/uvo2xdxk/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link.

https://jsfiddle.net/uvo2xdxk/7/

```
      .name {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.delete {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline;
     margin-right: 0px;
}

.price {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.row {
    width: 450px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:table;
}

.info {


    height:57px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: ccc;
    border: 1px solid green;
    top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: This is how it looks on my screen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MQSgy.png

Comment: No, the info box shall be on far right side.

Comment: You can have a look now i Have updated it. Link:  https://jsfiddle.net/uvo2xdxk/7/

Answer (score 0):

Add to your .info:

```
.info{
//...
    position: absolute;              
    top: 50%;                        
    transform: translate(0, -50%)
}
```

And your .row should set:

```
position: relative;
```

I had updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvo2xdxk/3/)

Comment: Doesn't work, have a look here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8NOxL.png

Comment: His question about making .info class in middle of .row class. Why you said that doesn't work? @@

Comment: Take a look at my attached screenshot. The red and blue box are vertically aligned to the yellow box, but not to the red one (which is the basic OP intention imho).

Comment: The red is .name class, not .row class! kindly check again. the yellow box is .row class.

Comment: You're right about that. But OP obviously want's to vertically align yellow, red, blue and green boxes!

Comment: I only answer the question "How can I make the .info div to be vertically aligned inside the row?" ^^. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your css please check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ge3g2rps/)

```
.name {
background-color: red;
display: inline;
float: left;
}

.delete {
background-color: green;
display: inline;
 margin-right: 25px;
}

.price {
background-color: blue;
display: inline;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.row {
width: 450px;
background-color: yellow;
border: 1px solid blue;
height: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

.info {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
background-color: ccc;
border: 1px solid green;
vertical-align: middle;
position:absolute;
right:0;
transform:translateY(-50%)   ;
top:50%;
}
```

Please check if it works for you.